# Can $PSL(2, p)$ be a subgroup of $PSL(2,q)$ if $p$ doesn't divide $q$?

Tags: group-theory, simple-groups

Let $p$ be a prime and let $q$ be a power of another prime. Suppose $p\nmid q$, then is it possible that $PSL(2, p)$ can be isomorphic to a subgroup of $PSL(2,q)$?

Any suggestion or reference is welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can happen if $p\in \{2,3,5\}$.

Look here for a list of the subgroups of $\mathrm{PSL}(2,q)$: https://www.staff.ncl.ac.uk/o.h.king/KingBCC05.pdf

You will see for example that $\mathrm{PSL}(2,5)(\cong A_5)$ occurs when $q\equiv \pm 1 \pmod {10}$.

You can do the same for $p\in\{2,3\}$ by remembering that $\mathrm{PSL}(2,3)\cong A_4$ and $\mathrm{PSL}(2,2)$ is a dihedral group of order $6$.

Comment: Thanks a lot @verret ! May I ask that whether the set $\{2,3,5\}$ is contains all the exceptional cases?

Comment: You can see that for yourself @LeoD. In $PSL(2,p)$ the $p$-elements are normalised by an element of order $\frac{p-1}{2}$, whereas in $PSL(2,q)$ the only powers of an element $a$ of order dividing $q\pm 1$ are $a, a^{-1}$. And if you know a little character theory you can prove that the exceptional cases do exist whenever the group  order allows it.

Comment: $PSL(2,5)$ also occurs when $q=2^{2m}$ but that doesn't *quite* count, as it is occurring as $PSL(2,4)$.

Comment: Thanks  @ancientmathematician. Could I ask more details about what you mean by "...the exceptional cases do exist whenever the group order allows it"? Do you mean that as long as the order of $PSL(2,p)$ divides that of $PSL(2,q)$, then the former can be realized as a subgroup of the later?

Comment: Yes, if 60 divides the order there's an $A_5=PSL(2,5)$, if 12 divides there's an $A_4=PSL(2,3)$ and of course 6 always divides, so there are always $D_6=PSL(2,2)$'s. (In fact if 24 divides there are $S_4$s but that's not the precise question here.) The argument I was shown years ago is this $A_5=\langle x,y\mid x^2=y^3=(xy)^5\rangle$, and by using character theory we can count the number of elements of orders 2, 3 whose product is order 5 - we'll get a nonzero answer. The other cases are similar. But there must be old-fashioned geometric arguments, too.